# data.table and aggregating out-of-order columns in result from by

Tags: r, data.table

Here's some interesting behavior that I noticed with data.table 1.9.2

```
>   testFun <- function(val) {
        if (val == 'geteeee') return(data.table(x=4,y=3))
        if (val == 'get') return(data.table(y=3,x=4))
    }
>   tbl = data.table(val=c('geteeee', 'get'))
>   tbl[, testFun(val), by=val]
       val x y
1: geteeee 4 3
2:     get 3 4
>
```

When the column order of the data tables returned from each call to testFun are mixed (but have the same name and number of columns), data.table silently binds the tables together without taking into account that they are out of order. This was probably done for speed, but I found the behavior quite unexpected, and would have appreciated at least a warning.

Is there a way that I can get data.table to warn or error when this situation happens, or (better yet) should it handle this case appropriately by reordering the columns so that the names line up? That's what rbind does if I understand that function correctly.

Comment: You are right. It was done for speed.

Comment: Yes, but `rbind` is designed just for that, binding rows. Why would you do this? I'm more inclined towards warning (`options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)` already tells something about named vectors already). Perhaps post it on the mailing list to discuss it further?

Comment: you should add an FR imo - I'd like to see this done "correctly" if the speed impact is minimal - it would help with a different class of problems, where you don't get the same number of columns in each by group (which I do encounter from time to time)

Comment: @.eddi I'll do that. @Arun. "Why would you do this?": Not on purpose :) But it happened in my analysis code, and caused values for two DVs to be intermixed.

Comment: @eddi, this would impact *all* other cases. Checking for every group if the evaluated names match would be costly (if not unnecessary). But yes a FR would be good.

Comment: @Arun you mean it will impact in terms of adding computing time - sure - perhaps it could be done optionally via a param (c.f. `rbind`)

Comment: @Arun @.Eddie. Sent an email out on the datatable-help mailing list. Should I close this question, as it turned out to be a FR and not something that I can solve at the moment?